# is electron's `safeStorage` for passwords and login credentials?

Tags: node.js, security, electron, credentials

I need to store login credentials with electron js because it doesnt save them like all browsers. I have seen a lot of questions like this, but I never found a solution. I have seen in the electron docs about the `safeStorage` feature. is the it safe enough/good enough to store login credentials on the client side? if not what other tools are available to do that? I have heard about `keytar` but is it good?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`safeStorage`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/safe-storage) api in electron exposes OS-level encryption/decryption **using current user's secret key** - please refer to [electron source](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/5d120359f6f6adf730455189d099b0a63a0e5cc9/shell/browser/api/electron_api_safe_storage.cc) and [chromium's `os_crypt`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/components/os_crypt/os_crypt_win.cc). On windows it utilizes [DPAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_API) while on *nixes it uses whatever password manager the OS has as the documentation suggested.

> is the it safe enough/good enough to store login credentials on the client side?

**Depends**, you should define "secure" first.

Ask yourself, should **the same user** allowed to read whatever value inside the encrypted text? A tech-literate person might write his own tools to decrypt things you store using that API you are out of luck. See [this QA](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/256928/132787) for further discussion.

> if not what other tools are available to do that?

There are a lot of tools (and encryption algorithm) to encrypt stuff in nodejs. However, you have to remember [**an encryption require you to have a key**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48493/how-does-an-encryption-key-work) of some sort and the key need to be protected too. Hence, try your best to avoid egg-chicken problem with your key of keys.

OS-based key storage avoids the key of keys problem by storing the "master key" in a way that only accessible using its API. At runtime, you can't retrieve the key at all, you just send a set of bytes for the OS to magically encrypt/decrypt. While at rest, the OS may rely on secure storage such as [TPM (Trusted Platform Module)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module).

> is electron's `safeStorage` for passwords and login credentials?

**Depends**, if you are running a web service it is preferrable to not doing so. You should never dump end user's user name/password directly on a storage that you can't guarantee its safety by yourself (e.g. your server). You should, put an identifier which can be revoked or may expire at later date - token or cookies.

Imagine the trouble when your end user device get stolen. If it's a token/cookie, they can request you to revoke their access from that device - similar to "Log me out from all other device."

However, if its an in-situ application that authenticates to itself then its a fair game - though keep in mind about the first point. Its all down to your security model.

Tl;dr [keytar](/questions/tagged/keytar):
Its a wrapper for [Windows Credentials](https://github.com/atom/node-keytar/blob/master/src/keytar_win.cc), [Libsecret](https://github.com/atom/node-keytar/blob/master/src/keytar_posix.cc), and [Keychain](https://github.com/atom/node-keytar/blob/master/src/keytar_mac.cc) as seen on the sources.

It basically do what `safeStorage` already do - relying on the platform to store stuff. Thats why it **depends** on the threat of who will be stealing the password.

Comment: thanks for the answer! but what about the keytar package https://www.npmjs.com/package/keytar ?

Comment: Also see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/748