# Where are VS Code extension secrets stored?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When using [SecretStorage in VS Code API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#SecretStorage) through an extension, where are the secrets stored, and is there a way for the user to view and edit them?

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the 1.80 release notes at https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_80#_secretstorage-api-now-uses-electron-api-over-keytar

Prior to 1.80, it used [keytar](https://github.com/atom/node-keytar), which is an abstraction layer over the OS's keyring. Keytar has been deprecated and [officially archived](https://github.com/atom/node-keytar), so in VS Code 1.80, it switched to using [Electron's `safeStorage` API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/safe-storage).

According to [this post by Begus Tesa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72952691/11107541):

> please refer to [electron source](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/5d120359f6f6adf730455189d099b0a63a0e5cc9/shell/browser/api/electron_api_safe_storage.cc) and [chromium's `os_crypt`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/components/os_crypt/os_crypt_win.cc). On windows it utilizes [DPAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_API) while on *nixes it uses whatever password manager the OS has as the documentation suggested.

The user would have to use whatever tools correspond to those platform-specific secret storage mechanisms.